# windows could not start the apache http server on local computer

Tags: php, apache

[image]In order to download PHPMyAdmin, I have to download its Prerequisites i.e apache & for apache Microsoft Visual Studio C++ 2019 than MySQL than PHP, and right after installing apache I run 'httpd' in cmd, http.exe file couldn't be opened but when I tried to open a browser and type localhost on address bar I received msg "it works!" and then when I start installing PHP I edit below lines in httpd.conf

> ```
> index.php right after index.html &
> ```

> ```
> LoadModule php7_module C:/php/php7apache2_4.dll
> ```

```
<IfModule php7_module>
    AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
    PHPIniDir "C:/php"
</IfModule>
```

and than i tried to start apache HTTP server from windows service but its showing the below error and then to resolve it I somehow got to know about XAMPP further I download XAMPP too with a little changes in ports it also starts apache 2.4 and MySQL but still not the APACHE HTTP SERVER

[image]

Comment: So have you reviewed the System Event Log yet, as the message told you?

Comment: there is nothing

Comment: And what do you get, when you try to start `httpd` via the command line now?

Comment: could you please suggest to me some solution

Comment: now its also showing error "httpd: Syntax error on line 74 of C:/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load C:/php/php7apache2_4.dll into server: The specified module could not be found."

Comment: Check if either of the two answers here help, https://stackoverflow.com/q/22266254/1427878

Comment: these are 7 years old ques I have a newer version of PHP

Comment: Doesn't change the fact, that you need up-to-date versions of any redistributable this might need, and that the module version and the Apache version must very specifically match. And what actual problem are you even trying to solve now? _"it also starts apache 2.4 and MySQL but still not the APACHE HTTP SERVER"_ - what "two apaches" are you talking about here in the first place? Either Apache started, or it didn't.

Comment: yes m also not getting it how have I done this mess apache 2.4 is running but not server

Comment: Sounds like you got lost in trying to install different "versions" of apache out of different sources now. I would recommend that you properly uninstall _all_ of it, and then you install just Xampp again. That is the newbie-friendlier alternative to trying to install & configure the components yourself, and usually runs pretty much out-of-the-box.

Comment: will xampp run phpmyadmin

Comment: If you download it from https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html, phpMyAdmin is already included.